# Plotting in Matlab 'while' loop

Tags: matlab, loops, plot

Why can't I plot data in every iteration in the same window? I tried with `drawnow`, but it isn't working. Code:

```
t=0;
T=10;
i =1;

while t<T
. . .

time(i)=(i-1)*delta_t;

scrsz = get(0,'ScreenSize');

figure('position',[80 60 scrsz(3)-110 scrsz(4)-150]);

subplot(1,3,1);
plot(time(i),configurations(1,1,i),'-b','LineWidth',2), hold on;
drawnow;
xlabel('Time[s]');
ylabel('X [m]');

subplot(1,3,2);
plot(time(i),configurations(3,1,i),'-b','LineWidth',2), hold on;
drawnow;
xlabel('Time[s]');
ylabel('Z [m]');

subplot(1,3,3);
plot(time(i),configurations(2,2,i),'-b','LineWidth',2), hold on;
drawnow;
xlabel('Time[s]');
ylabel('\phi [deg]');

t=t+1;
i=i+1;

end
```

Comment: Please define "isn't working".

Comment: It plots data in new window in every iteration. I have 10 plot windows at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you've added the `figure('...')` line *inside* the `while` loop. So it opens a new window every iteration. Move that line and the `scrsz=...` line and place it just above the `while t<T` line (i.e., *outside* the loop).

To plot to more than one figure window, use axes handles like so:

```
hFig1=figure(1);hAxes1=axes;
hFig2=figure(2);hAxes2=axes;

while ...
    ---
    plot(hAxes1,...)
    plot(hAxes2,...)
end
```

However, each `subplot` creates an axis of its own. So if you want to plot to multiple subplots in two different windows inside the loop, you'll have to set them up *before* the loop and then call accodringly. i.e.,

```
hFig1=figure(1);
hAxes1Sub1=subplot(1,2,1);
hAxes1Sub2=subplot(1,2,2);

hFig2=figure(2);
hAxes2Sub1=subplot(1,2,1);
hAxes2Sub2=subplot(1,2,2);

while ...
    ---
    plot(hAxes1Sub1,...)
    plot(hAxes2Sub1,...)
end
```

Comment: And if I have two separate plot functions inside the same loop? Can I just name this figure somehow?

Comment: I tried to place 'scrsz' and 'h = figure('position',[80 60 scrsz(3)-110 scrsz(4)-150]);' above the while loop, and in the loop 'plot(h,time(i),configurations(1,1,i),'-b','LineWidth',2), hold on;'. No success.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't name it `hAxes...` in one place and `hAxis...` elsewhere? Note the `i` and the `e`